# How to configure multi-language site in gruntfile.js?

Tags: gruntjs, assemble

I have a problem that every time I run `grunt assemble` in the terminal, the task will never complete. Here is my `assemble` task in gruntfile.js, can someone please tell me if there are anything wrong with it?

```
   assemble: {
        options: {
            flatten: true,
            assets: '<%= config.tmp %>/assets',
            layout: ['<%= config.src %>/templates/layouts/default.hbs'],
            //data: '<%= config.src %>/data/*.{json,yml}',
            data: ['<%= config.src %>/data/**/*.{json,yml}'],
            partials: ['<%= config.src %>/templates/partials/*.hbs'],
            plugins: ['assemble-contrib-anchors',
                'assemble-contrib-permalinks',
                'assemble-contrib-toc',
                'assemble-contrib-i18n',
                'assemble-contrib-contextual'
            ], //'assemble-contrib-sitemap'
            contextual: {
                dest: '<%= config.tmp %>/'
            },
            i18n: {
                // data: ['<%= config.src %>/data/i18n.json'],
                // templates: ['<%= config.src %>/templates/*.hbs']
                languages: buildLanguages, // buildLanguages = ['en','de','ru']
                templates: ['<%= config.src %>/templates/pages/*.hbs']
            },
            permalinks: {
                structure: ':language/:file:ext'
            },
            files: {
                '<%= config.src %>/': ['<%= config.src %>/templates/pages/*.hbs']
            }
        },
        dist: {
            files: [
                {
                    src: '<%= config.src %>/templates/pages/*.hbs',
                    dest: '<%= config.tmp %>/'
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

I used `grunt assemble --verbose` and it outputs the following messages:

```
Assembling pages...

{ _page: 'all',
  dirname: '.tmp',
  filename: 'products-en.html',
  pageName: 'products-en.html',
  pagename: 'products-en.html',
  basename: 'products-en',
  src: 'src/templates/pages/products-en.hbs',
  dest: '.tmp/en/products.html',
  assets: '../assets',
  ext: '.html',
  extname: '.html',
  page: '\n\n<h1>Products!</h1>',
  data: { language: 'en', file: 'products' },
  filePair: 
   { src: [Getter],
     dest: '.tmp/',
     orig: { src: [Object], dest: '.tmp/' } },
  index: 3,
  number: 4,
  first: false,
  prev: 2,
  middle: true,
  next: 4,
  last: false,
  slug: 'products-en',
  isCurrentPage: false,
  relativeLink: 'products.html' }
Currentpage: [object Object]
Variables loaded
```

But when I look into my .tmp folder, there is no `.tmp/en/product.html` file.

Comment: What does `grunt --verbose` say?

Comment: it outputs that the generated files are stored at some folder, but when I check there, there is no file in those folders.

Comment: Maybe attach some of the output?  And when you say 'the task will never complete' you mean...it hangs and you have to break execution?  Or...something else?  Details about the results are kind of important.

Comment: Yes, I mean it hangs there until I break execution. I have attached the output when use `grunt assemble --verbose` .

Comment: I commented on the other question - not sure which you want to use, but you should delete one or the other.