# Grunt assemble is not generating static page

Tags: gruntjs, assemble

I used `grunt assemble --verbose` and it outputs the following messages:

```
Assembling pages...

{ _page: 'all',
  dirname: '.tmp',
  filename: 'products-en.html',
  pageName: 'products-en.html',
  pagename: 'products-en.html',
  basename: 'products-en',
  src: 'src/templates/pages/products-en.hbs',
  dest: '.tmp/en/products.html',
  assets: '../assets',
  ext: '.html',
  extname: '.html',
  page: '\n\n<h1>Products!</h1>',
  data: { language: 'en', file: 'products' },
  filePair: 
   { src: [Getter],
     dest: '.tmp/',
     orig: { src: [Object], dest: '.tmp/' } },
  index: 3,
  number: 4,
  first: false,
  prev: 2,
  middle: true,
  next: 4,
  last: false,
  slug: 'products-en',
  isCurrentPage: false,
  relativeLink: 'products.html' }
Currentpage: [object Object]
Variables loaded
```

But when I look into my .tmp folder, there is no `.tmp/en/products.html` file. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Are you asking the same question multiple times?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498069/how-to-configure-multi-language-site-in-gruntfile-js  Rather than open new questions, you can edit the original with the new information...

Comment: The object shows `dest: '.tmp/en/products.html'` and your calling `.tmp/en/product.html`, is that accurate?

Comment: typo...  I meant that whole .tmp folder doesn't have anything, not even en subfolder..